# jQuery post being received as array with expressjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a client side ajax post via jquery such as this:

```
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
      one: 'test',
      two: 'testing',
      three: [1,2,3,4]
    },
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
  });
```

I have an express server that uses `body-parser` and for some reason it's being received on the server as this:

```
{ 
 one: 'test',
 two: 'testing',
 'three[]': [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ] 
}
```

Any idea why `three` is setup like an array but a string? Would like it to be simply `'three' : [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]`

Answer (score 0):

make sure in your express app you have this setup with bodyParser

```
app.use(
    bodyParser.json() //create application/json parser

    );
```

also in ajax request you have not set the contentType to application/json.
by default it is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
so change your request to

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: {
      one: 'test',
      two: 'testing',
      three: [1,2,3,4]
    },
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
  });
```

This should do it

Comment: With `contentType: 'application/json'` I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: ` contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

also add 
`dataType:"json",`